# copy-webpack-plugin doesn't copy files

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I try to just copy files to check simple webpack config. So I stuck trying to make copy-webpack-plugin to work - nothing happens: no copied files, no errors, nothing

Common config (webpack.common.js):

```
const path = require('path');

const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');

const postCssPlugin = [
  require('postcss-import'),
  require('postcss-nested'),
  require('postcss-simple-vars'),
  require('autoprefixer')({
    browsers: [
      'last 3 versions',
      'android 4.2'
    ]
  })
];

module.exports = {
  context: path.resolve(__dirname, '../src'),
  entry: [
    'babel-polyfill',
    path.resolve(__dirname, '../src/index.js')
  ],
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, '../dist/js'),
    publicPath: '',
    filename: 'app.js'
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.jsx', '.js', '.json']
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'babel-loader'
      },
      {
        test: /\.p?css$/,
        use: [
          'style-loader',
          'css-loader',
          {
            loader: 'postcss-loader',
            options: {
              ident: 'postcss',
              plugins: postCssPlugin
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new CopyWebpackPlugin([
      {
        from: path.resolve(__dirname, '../src/assets/**/*'),
        to: path.resolve(__dirname, '../dist/assets'),
        flatten: true
      }
    ])
  ],
  stats: {
    modules: true,
    warnings: false,
    version: true,
    timings: true,
    performance: false,
    hash: true,
    errors: true,
    errorDetails: true,
    colors: true,
    builtAt: true
  }
};
```

webpack.prod.js:

```
const commonWebpackConfig = require('./webpack.common.js');

const UglifyJsWebpackPlugin = require('uglifyjs-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = Object.assign(commonWebpackConfig, {
  mode: 'production',
  plugins: [
    new UglifyJsWebpackPlugin({
      sourceMap: true
    })
  ]
});
```

And build starting file build.js:

```
const webpack = require('webpack');

const webpackProdConfig = require('./webpack.config/webpack.prod.js');

webpack(webpackProdConfig, (err, stats) => {
  if (err || stats.hasErrors()) {
    console.error(err.stack || err);
  }

  console.log('Successfully compiled!');
});
```

So could anyone figure out why doesn't it work and where am I wrong?
copy-webpack-plugin: 4.5.2
node: 9.1.0
npm: 6.3.0
windows: 10

Addition - folder structure:

[image]

Comment: can you show the project folder structure. I think the issue can be in path of files in copy webpack plugin

Comment: @MohitTilwani yeah, added screenshot to the question

Answer (score 4):

Just spent 3 days on this.
If you're on webpack 5, you probably only need writeToDisk turned on.

```js
{
  devServer: {
   devMiddleware: { writeToDisk: true }
  }
}
```

Comment: Why does this not have more upvotes? It solved the problem exactly! Thank you!

Comment: This was the only solution that worked for me. Spent 2 hours on this myself.

Answer (score 2):

Try to copy from the dist folder. For me it worked
es.

```
new CopywebpackPlugin([{
    from: path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules/mettrr-component-library/dist/img'),
    to: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/assets/img')
}]),
```

Answer (score 0):

In this specific example it's [`Object.assign()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) causing the configuration issue.

`Object.assign()` copies properties from the source onto the destintation, but it does not merge arrays or objects.

So your original configuration is equivalent to writing this code:

```
const commonWebpackConfig = require('./webpack.common.js');

const UglifyJsWebpackPlugin = require('uglifyjs-webpack-plugin');

const productionConfig = {
  mode: 'production',
  plugins: [
    new UglifyJsWebpackPlugin({
      sourceMap: true
    })
  ]
};

// This is the equivalent of what `Object.assign()` is doing in your original code
commonWebpackConfig.mode = productionConfig.mode;
commonWebpackConfig.plugins = productionConfig.plugins; // oops, this replaces the previous `plugins` list

module.exports = commonWebpackConfig;
```

With this rewritten code you can see that the `plugins` array is not being merged (it's being replaced) and that is why `CopyWebpackPlugin` isn't working, it doesn't exist in your final config.

---

With newer JavaScript code like [`...` spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) it's possible to do a manual merge of the config.

This allows you to merge both `plugins` arrays and get a working config:

```
const commonWebpackConfig = require('./webpack.common.js');

const UglifyJsWebpackPlugin = require('uglifyjs-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  ...commonWebpackConfig,
  mode: 'production',
  plugins: [
    ...commonWebpackConfig.plugins,
    new UglifyJsWebpackPlugin({
      sourceMap: true
    }),
  ]
});
```